# Failing data insert in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, web, sql-insert

I need to add records into the table 'writings'. As you can see in the code below, the failure leds to the message `data insert failed`.

I've already tried to change everything that  online forums adviced but it didnt help. All the program outputs is `data insert failed` and thats all. When I tried to add `mysql_errno`, it gave error code `0`, which,as I remember, means that operation was successful.

**The main code:**

```
<?php
include 'dbcon.php';
$Title=$_GET['Title'];
$TaskID=$_GET['TaskID'];
$uid=$_GET['uid'];
$Text=$_GET['Text'];
$Date=$_GET['Date'];
$result=mysqli_query($MySQLiconn,"insert into 'writings'(uid,TaskID,Date,Text,Title, comment) values('$uid','$TaskID','$Date','$Text','$Title','')");
if ($result) {
    echo "Successfully added.<br>";
} else {
    echo "Data insert failed <br><br>";
}
```

**The file DBcon**

```
<?php
     $DB_host = "localhost";
     $DB_user = "root";
     $DB_pass = "";
     $DB_name = "web";

     $MySQLiconn = new MySQLi($DB_host,$DB_user,$DB_pass,$DB_name);

     if($MySQLiconn->connect_errno)
     {
         die("ERROR : -> ".$MySQLiconn->connect_error);
     }
```

Comment: Use the error reporting function instead of just saying `failed`. Parameterize your query. Don't quote the table name. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO writings (uid, TaskID, Date, Text, Title, comment)
VALUES ('$uid','$TaskID','$Date','$Text','$Title','')";

$result = mysql_query( $sql, $MySQLiconn );
if(! $result )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
```

Comment: @AleksandraLee Do not use this, there are numerous issues here. Value of `$sql` needs to be quoted. `mysql_*` is deprecated or removed (depending on version). `mysql_` wouldnt work with `$MySQLiconn`. Still open to injections. Pretty much this is the same as what you had but for versions of PHP for pre-2009.